# JQuery UI Slider not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just started playing with JQuery UI slider, haven't been able to display it on my page. Tried bunch of things bit to no avail. Heres my code, any suggestions would be much appreciated. Am using Django for referring to the javascript files,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Results</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>


        <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
        <style>
            #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#slider" ).slider();
            });
        </script>
    <div class="demo">

        <div id="slider"></div>

    </div><!-- End demo -->



    <div class="demo-description">
    <p>The basic slider is horizontal and has a single handle that can be moved with the mouse or by using the arrow keys.</p>
    </div><!-- End demo-description -->
</body>
```

Comment: im not sure what django is but the first thing i notice is that this page lacks the necessary jquery UI stylesheets.

Comment: thanks Lauw, I edited and added the css link, still no luck. The text in the <p> tag  is displayed but not the slider.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI is quite easy to setup.  Simply reference the appropriate CSS/JavaScript files in the document `<head>` tag.

> **Code in `<head>` tag**:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

> **Slider Initialization HTML**:

```
<div id='mockSlider'></div>
<input type='text' id='currentValue' />
```

> **Slider Initialization jQuery**:

```
$("#mockSlider").slider({
    range: false,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        doSomething(ui.value);
    }
});

function doSomething(sliderValue) {
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('value', sliderValue);
}
```

> **Slider Initialization CSS**:

```
#mockSlider {
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#currentValue {
    width: 3empx;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Follow the link below to see an jsFiddle example. Specifically, take a look under the external resources menu, where you will see the 3 code references.  Then, press F12 and use the debugging selection tool to see what is in the `<head>` of the rendered document.

> [Example Slider](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/th24mhtd/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any javascript errors when loading the page ? If so what is it ?

Can you make sure your javascripts (jqyeru ui) are loaded properly ?

If you use firebug, you can see the errors in the console tab. FireBig is a firefox addon which makes web development a lot easier

[www.getfirebug.com](http://www.getfirebug.com)

Comment: thanks Shyju, you were right, the order of the js files was incorrect. I fixed it, getting no errors in firebug. Although, now I see a blank line in window where the slider should appear, still don't see it. Updated the changes I made.

Comment: It seems to me like it is still your css file that isnt included properly.. instead of what you are using, try using external resources. f.e: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css as CSS file --- watch here: http://jsfiddle.net/9QDuM/6/

Comment: Lauw, thanks much, I added the following,                                                           <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery-ui-1.8.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css">                          and it is now being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle.net link as well, is pretty nifty.

Comment: Adding the link to the stylesheet resolved a similar error I had! +1

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes jquery ui widgets not showing may be due to missing jquery-ui-scope div.   All jquery ui styles are defined within the scope of div with jquery-ui-scope class.